# Xml - '=' is an unexpected token, the expected token is ';'

Tags: c#, xml

i'm using this code to read a xml file

```
string xmlcontents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("the xml path");
xml.LoadXml(xmlcontents);
```

when i execute this code it gives me this error

> System.Xml.XmlException: ''=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'

here is the xml line with the error

```
<SubMenu name="Assassins Creed Origins" picture="https://image.ibb.co/gqeqpd/image.jpg" Torrent="http://rarbg.to/download.php?id=hzvlmyb&f=The.Endless.2017.1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG-[rarbg.to].torrent" />
```

the error is in the Torrent attribute, its because the link contains `&` and replacing it with `&amp;` will fix the problem, but if i do that the link will be incorrect, how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: As you say `the link will be incorrect`. I think you should also include how and when you use the content of the `Torrent` attribute, as it seems a potential [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You need to encode/decode the value of Torrent. Encode when store to xml and decode when read from xml

Comment: The XML content you have is invalid. Where do you get the XML content from or how did you generate it. Please add the source code you have and any informations to your question.

Comment: Have you tried replacing & in the url with %38

Comment: You have a special character in the xml.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Where did you get this xml file? Did you create it yourself? Show us how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it stands that is invalid XML. You will need to encode the `&` as `&amp;`. When you read it out from your XML document, it will be just `&`.

Comment: i have tried it, when i get the attribute value it gets `&amp;` instead of just `&`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax rules of XML are strict and to make it valid, you need to use **&amp** instead of **&**.

To work with XML, you can escape and decode special characters.
Here are some examples to understand how encoding works:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx

Based on this you can reverse this process.

Also to validate XML's you can use: https://validator.w3.org/

Hope it helps